# Server/Client live updates

Tags: java, angular, spring

I have some problems understanding the best concept for my problem.
My architecure is pretty basic. I have a backend with data that can be updated and clients which will load data with some filtes.

I have a backend that has the data in a EHCache.
The data model is pretty basic for example

```
{
  id: string,
  startDate: date,
  endDate: date,
  username: string,
  group: string
}
```

The data can only be modified by another backend service.
When data is modified, added or deleted we have an data update event generated.

The clients are all web clients and have a Spring boot REST Service to fetch the data from the cache.
For the data request the clients sends his own request settings. There are different settings like date and text filter. For example

```
{
  contentFilter: Filter,
  startDateFilter: date,
  endDateFilter: date
}
```

The backend use this settings to filter the data from the cache and then sends the response with the filtered data.

When the cache generates an update event every client gets notified by a websocket connection.
And then request the full data with the same request settings as before.

My problem is now that there are many cache updates happening and that the clients can have a lots of data to load if the full dataset is loaded everytime.

For example I have this scenario.

```
Full dataset in cache: 100 000 rows
Update of rows in cache: 5-10 random rows every 1-5 seconds
Client1 dataset with request filter: 5000 rows
Client2 dataset with request filter: 50 rows
```

Now everytime the client receives a update notification the client will load the complete dataset (5000 rows) and that every 1-5 seconds. If the update only happens on the same row everytime and the row isn´t loaded by the client because of his filter settings then the client would be loading the data unnecessarily.

I am not sure what would be the best solution to reduce the client updates and increase the performance.

My first thought was to just send the updated line directly with the websocket connection to the clients.
But for that I would have to know if the client "needs" the updated line. If the updates are happening on rows that the clients doesn´t need to load because of the filter settings then I would spam the client with unnecessary updates.
I could add a check on the client side if the id of the updated row is in the loaded dataset but then I would need a separate check if a row is added to the cache instead of an update.

But I am not sure if that is the best practice. And unfortunately I can not find many resources about this topic.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient things are always the most work, sadly.

I won't claim to be an expert at this kind of thing - on either the implementation(s) available or even the best practices - but I can give some food for thought at least, which may or may not be of help.

My first choice: your first thought.

You have the problem of knowing if the updated item is relevant to the client, due to the filters.

Save the filters for the client whenever they request the full data set!

Row gets updated, check through all the client filters to see if it is relevant to any of them, push out to those it is.

The effort for maintaining that filter cache is minimal (update whenever they change their filters), and you'll also be sending down minimal data to the clients. You also won't be iterating over a large dataset multiple times, just the smaller client set and only for the few rows that have been updated.

Another option:

If you don't go ahead with option 1, option 2 might be to group updates - assuming you have the luxury of not needing *immediate*, *real-time* updates.

Instead of telling the clients about *every* data update, only tell them every x seconds that there might be data waiting for them (*might be*, you little tease).

I was going to add other options but, to be honest, I don't see why you'd worry about much beyond option 1, maybe with an option 2 addition to reduce traffic if that's an issue.

'Best practice'-wise, sending down multiple FULL datasets to multiple clients multiple times a second is certainly not it.

Sending only the data relevant to each client is a much better solution, and if you can further reduce how much the client even needs to send (i.e. only their filter *updates* and not have them re-send something you could already have saved) is an added bonus.

---

Edit:

Ah, stateless server - though it's not really stateless. You're using web sockets, so the server has some kind of state for those connections. It's already stateful so option 1 doesn't really break anything.

If it's to be completely stateless, then you also can't store the updated rows of data, so you can't return those individually. You're back to what you're doing which is a full round-trip and data read + serve.

Option 3, though, if you're semi stateless (don't want to add any metadata to those socket connections) but do hold updated rows: timestamp them and have the clients send the time of their last update along with their filters - you can then return only the updated rows since their last update using their provided filters (timestamp becomes just another filter) (or maybe it is stateless, but the timestamp becomes another filter).

Either way, limiting the updated data back down to the client is the main goal if for nothing else than saving data transfer.

---

Edit 2:

Sounds like you may need to send two bits of data down (or three if you want to split things even further - makes life easier client-side, I guess):

```json
{
    newItems: [{...}, ...],
    updatedItems: [{...}, ...],
    deletedIds: [1,2...]
}
```

Yes, when their request for an update comes, you'll have to check through your updated items to see if any are deleted and of relevance to the client's filters, but you can send down a minimal list of ids rather than whole rows that your client can then remove.

Comment: Thank you for your response. We already have some grouping integrated. So if there are many updates comming we will wait some seconds an group the updates. I also thought about the storing the client filter. But then that would be against the stateless server concept because I would have to have the clients states on the server side.

Comment: For returning the updated rows individually I wouldn´t store them I would just send them with the update notification where the updated rows are included. But yeah of course with the websocket sessions I have some kind of state stored. Your option 3 is a good solution. I was thinkig about that and I am debating now if I want that or if I want to store the state/filter of the clients.

Comment: One problem that I would have with the timestamp solutions is what if an row gets deleted or if an update of a row will result that the client doesn´t need the row anymore because of his filter. Then a new request with the timestamp would not help. So I would have to check if there are any rows that has to be removed on the client side which can be the result of the update of the row and the client filter. So I would have to know if the row was loaded from the client before the update or check the row with client filter when the row is updated.

Comment: As I said: `The most efficient things are always the most work, sadly.`. Yes, if you want efficient, you need to make things smarter, which means more work, which means more state. They can't magically know things, there isn't an easy solution.